# Decreasing amount turns on coils decreased my rpm?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

So after reading link after link of how torque and speed are inversely proportional, I deduced that if I decreased the magnetic flux, my motor should run faster albeit with less torque. However, when I redid my windings from 300 turns each to 100 turns each, my motor barely moved! It went from 2500 to like 400rpm. What gives?

Motor specs: hand made brushless dc motor, 3 coils of 28 gauge wire, 12V, 1 permanent magnet pair, and vex optical shaft encoder used for 6 step commutation

Comment: If the coil saturating?

Comment: I'm using air cores

Comment: Decreasing magnetic flux will produce less torque, how come did you expect the motor to spin faster? The higher speed you need to achive the higher torque you need to overcome the friction

Comment: Oh, I see your mistake! “torque and speed are inversely proportional”: that’s true when you say that the more speed your motor spins the less torque it’s generating, but it doesn’t mean the less torque you generate the higher speed your motor spins...!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If the lower torque drops below the frictional torque of the motor, then that's what you'll see. It needs a fairly efficient motor for the lower torque to be adequate to turn it. A home-brew air-cored motor will likely have very poor efficiency.

When doing experiments like this, it's easier to spin the machine as a generator, and measure the voltage developed. If you do that you'll see the developed voltage has dropped to a third (so the speed/voltage k has dropped), and that the shaft is a bit easier to turn (so the torque/current k has changed correspondingly).

Comment: So you're saying that my friction is too much for the lower torque, so in order to spin the speed lowers more than the speed it gained in order to generate enough torque? In that case, is there some sort of sweet spot between 100 and 300 turns that'll give me more speed while maintaining enough torque to beat friction?

Comment: (a) probably and (b) maybe but without knowing more about the motor you'd have to find out by experiment. Brushless motors are fairly low friction anyway (no brushes!) so you also have to ask how well your BLDC controller can drive 1/9 the impedance it was designed to drive...

Comment: I don't think the controller is the issue, i built and coded it myself with the correct phase shift to keep the torque around 90 degrees as much as possible. My bearings are not very good and this vex encoder has a ton of friction, so I think that's more than likely the problem. I'm going to take apart the encoder and rebuild it as frictionless as possible, and ill go ahead and order some actual ball bearings and see how that helps